# Custom prop children with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In [the react (15.4.1) docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), it says that instead of using `props.children` for including components, it is also possible to use custom properties `props.left` and `props.right` to include multiple children in components with "holes".

How can this approach be realized when using React Router (3.0.0)? The `component={MyComponent}` syntax does not seem to allow including multiple children.

I want to able to write something like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route component={App} >
    <Route component={Page}>
      <Route page='/' component={Header}>           <-- 1st child of Page
        <Route component={Logo} />                    <-- 1st child of Header
        <Route component={Nav} />                     <-- 2nd child of Header
      </Route>
      <Route page='/' component={Home} />           <-- 2nd child of Page
      <Route page='/custom' component={Custom} />   <-- 2nd child of Page, 2nd route
    </Route>
  </Route>
<Router>
```

I am aware that I can do the nesting within the components, but then I have various components imports spread accross my files, which increases dependencies and makes it hard to track which component is used where.

I would like to keep all component dependencies in the one file that defines the routing structure.

Comment: `components={{ c1: Logo, c2: Nav }}` https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1

Comment: @azium This works, but only for one level of nesting. Assume, ```nav``` again would have two children, how would they be added in the next nested Route? I tried with the same method, just referring to the props name, it doesn't work on the 2nd level.

Comment: Can you update your example code to show that? In your "example" code Logo and Nav are not actually routes they are just components so inside the nav component you can put whatever you like

Comment: You are right, I think I am using Router the wrong way. I will rather do the nesting inside the components and use Routes only for switching content.